# Documentation for Tesla polyglot?

Tags: maven, polyglot

I stumbled over [Tesla Polyglot](https://github.com/takari/maven-polyglot) for Maven, but I can't find documentation, is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that all the updated information is on GitHub now

[GitHub Maven Polyglot](https://github.com/takari/polyglot-maven)

Answer (score 1):

There are some recent posts about Polyglot for Maven on the [Takari Blog](http://takari.io/2015/03/19/polyglot-maven.html), also containing links to an example repository on GitHub.